# Unable to retrieve application added cookie

Tags: jsp, cookies

iam having a jsp page Index.jsp which accept a only unicode string as its parameter and submit the form to Result.jsp. I need to maintain the cookie for the string entered by the user each time user enter the new string cookie value would be changed i have wriiten following code

In Index.jsp i have crated the Cookie

```
<%
        Cookie ck= new Cookie("DNString",";");
        response.addCookie(ck);
%>
```

and in the servlet i am trying to manage and set the cookie value each tim euser submits the form

```
private void fnSetCookieValues(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
    {

        Cookie[] cookies=request.getCookies();
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(""+cookies.length+"Name"+cookies[i].getName());
            if(cookies[i].getName().equals("DNString"))
            {   
                System.out.println("Inside if:: "+cookies[i].getValue()+""+cookies.length);
                cookies[i].setValue(request.getParameter("txtIIDN"));
            }
        }

    }
```

but the problem is that while getCookie() it doesnt give the DNString as the cookie but only shows **1NameJSESSIONID** as System.out.println(""+cookies.length+"Name"+cookies[i].getName()); statement output

but while looking througn browser like

[image]
it shows DNString as a cookie stored

can anyone figure out the problem and possible solution for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be because of `;` being the delimiter of cookie parameters.

The value `";"` added for the first time goes to the client with response header like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: tomcat
Set-Cookie: DNSString=;;JSESSIONID=some-id-value
...
...
```

The client sends back the cookie in the next request like this:

```
GET /someurl Http/1.1
Host: server.com
Cookie: DNSString=;;JSESSIONID=some-id-value
```

**I think somewhere the parsing is failing because the value itself is delimiter.**

Comment: but i think                                                   Cookie ck= new Cookie("DNString",";");                  response.addCookie(ck); have already created the cookie and added to the response object which will sent it to client side

Comment: yes, that is for the first time. But, you cannot modify cookies you get it from HttpServletRequest.getCookies().Modiying such cookies will not resend the cookie to client. The client will still have the old value.

Comment: Sorry but im not getting what you want to explain ..but i am not even getting my cookie DNString using HttpServletRequest.getCookies() method it only returns 1NameJSESSIONID not DNString

Comment: what is the cookies.length you are getting

Comment: its 1 always which might be cookie JSESSIONID

Comment: here the problem is not with modyfying cookie value but retriving it from the client end with HttpServletRequest.getCookies() atleast it should return the cookie with the name DNString .If cookie is not stored on client side so why is it showing DNString in the browser cookie option shown in the image

Comment: Can u try adding some other value than ";" for the first time.

Comment: yes cant believe this might be the problem but now i can read the cookie DNString using getCookie() method just by changing the value from ";" to say "abc" Thanks Ramesh PVK! any reason why is it ?

Comment: Modified my answer. Please check