# unable to retrieve cookie value using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is the java code where I create the cookie.

```
Cookie c= new Cookie("pass", "abc");
response.addCookie(c);
```

And this is the JSP page where I am trying to retrieve the cookie details.

```
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*, javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<% Cookie[] cookie=request.getCookies();
String passwd="pass";
for (int i = 0; i < cookie.length; i++) {
   if(cookie[i].getName().equals("pass"))
   {
     passwd=cookie[i].getValue();
   }
 }
%>
<label for="pwd">Password : </label><input type="text" id="pwd" name="pass" value=<%=passwd%>></input>
```

[Unable to retrieve application added cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096352/unable-to-retrieve-application-added-cookie)
This question is somewhat related to my problem though the answer dint help me.

Comment: Look in the browser what cookies are set. It might be the path "/xyz/uvw" != "/abc". That will help. (If you want session cookies use `setMaxAge(-1)`.)

Comment: Make sure that cookies are enabled in your browser..

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Joop Eggen. But when I check the cookie details on the browser, the cookie is getting created and it is a session cookie itself. Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Code Dreamer. But cookies are enabled on my browser and the cookie is getting created as well. Only retrieving data from the cookie is causing a problem. Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: To be sure - And the path is okay too? If created in /xyz, it is not seen in /uvw. Firefox shows the paths too. `cookie.setPath(servletContent);` or so. Maybe http/https (`setSecure`).

Comment: Thank you @JoopEggen. The cookie path was the problem. I set the path and now i can retrieve the details.

Comment: @Rohan Britto Don't forget that you can answer your own question. Just add the answer and accept so that question wont be left open

Comment: Passing password around in a cookie is a huge security hole. If the sole purpose is to redisplay the submitted value, then you're doing it the completely wrong way. Cookies should not be used at all for this.

Comment: I am new to servlets @BalusC. If you could suggest some better ways to pass password from a jsp to a servlet or vice-versa, it would be more than appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comments. I had not set the path. For eg. If cookie is created in /xyz, it is not seen in /uvw. Now my code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use `${cookie.pass.value}` to get the value of the pass cookie